How to create a transition matrix from 3 rasters using gdistance
I have a dummy raster
nrows <- 4
ncols <- 7
ras <- raster(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncols)
values(rast) <- 1:(nrows * ncols)

And I have three rasters that represent the speed of going from a cell to the north, to the sides and to the back like this.
n <- ncell(raster_test)
speed_up <- raster(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncols)
values(speed_up) <- rep(3,n)

speed_sides <- raster(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncols)
values(speed_sides) <- rep(2,n)

speed_down <- raster(nrows = nrows, ncols = ncols)
values(speed_down) <- rep(1,n)

I want to find the fastest path from one point to another taking into account that the speed of each difrection is different. The speed of going diagonal should be the average of the orthogonal speeds. I dont know how to appropiately create the transition matrix.
